# Make drawstring partially bold

Tags: vb.net, graphics, treeviewitem, drawstring

Good morning.

I have created a custom treeview control that paints a normal treeview onto the screen, plus various other things. During the paint event I draw the node.text string to the treeview control using the following method.

```
node.text = "ABCDEFG"
g.DrawString(node.Text, tvFont, Brushes.Black, strPosX + 10, bothPosY)
```

Basically what I am trying to do is make part of the node.text italic, so that it renders on screen like so...

```
AB*CDE*FG
```

Personally I would approach this in such a way that it effectively draws three different strings... two non-italic and one italic, however this would require additional positioning.

I am hoping that it is possible to effectively concatinate font formated strings then place that as the first parameter in drawstring, is this actually possible? If so how would I go about doing it and/or are there any resources that would help me.

I am using winforms, and visualbasic .net framework 3.5 (unfortuantly non of the aforementioned can be changed as it is a work project and this is the environment the software is designed for)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am hoping that it is possible to effectively concatinate font formated strings then place that as the first parameter in drawstring, is this actually possible?

No, this is not possible. The `DrawString` function is going to draw all of the text you specify using the formatting flags that you specify. It's an all-or-nothing affair.

If you want to make some portions bold and other portions not, then you will need to make multiple calls to the `DrawString` function. There is some additional positioning involved to accomplish that, but it shouldn't be too difficult. Only the x-coordinate is changing; the y-coordinate should stay the same. Unless you do something fancy like change *font faces*, then [your baselines will get messed up and you will have to compensate for that to prevent the result from looking like an ugly mismatch](https://web.archive.org/web/20141006045800/http://bobpowell.net/formattingtext.aspx).

Aside from that, allow me to recommend that you use the [`TextRenderer.DrawText` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.drawtext) instead of the `Graphics.DrawString` function. The advantage of the former is that it draws text using GDI, which is the same way that the built-in native controls draw their text. There are a number of advantages to this consistency, not the least of which is a pleasing and harmonious visual appearance.

And if you're using `TextRenderer.DrawText`, you'll also want to make sure that you combine it with [`TextRenderer.MeasureText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext), because the measurements will be different from those returned by [`Graphics.MeasureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring), which draws using GDI+.

More information on the difference between `TextRenderer.DrawText` and `Graphics.DrawString` is available in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268238/drawing-text-in-net). `Graphics.DrawString` should be reserved for printing, and `TextRenderer.DrawText` should be used for all on-screen elements.

Comment: I guessed that this was pretty much the case, however a big thumbs up for the textrenderer.drawtext function :)

Answer (score 3):

How about something like:

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    using (Font normal = new Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Regular))
    using (Font bold = new Font("Tahoma", 10, FontStyle.Bold))
    using (StringFormat format = 
        (StringFormat)StringFormat.GenericTypographic.Clone())
    {
        format.FormatFlags |= StringFormatFlags.MeasureTrailingSpaces;
        Rectangle temp = ClientRectangle;

        DrawString(e.Graphics, SystemBrushes.WindowText, ref temp, format, "AB", normal);
        DrawString(e.Graphics, SystemBrushes.WindowText, ref temp, format, "CDE ", bold);
        DrawString(e.Graphics, SystemBrushes.WindowText, ref temp, format, "FG", normal);
    }
}

void DrawString(Graphics g, Brush brush, ref Rectangle rect, StringFormat format, string text, Font font)
{
    using (StringFormat copy = (StringFormat)format.Clone())
    {
        copy.SetMeasurableCharacterRanges(new CharacterRange[] {
        new CharacterRange(0, text.Length)});
        Region[] regions = g.MeasureCharacterRanges(text, font, rect, copy);

        g.DrawString(text, font, brush, rect, format);

        int width = (int)(regions[0].GetBounds(g).Width);
        rect.X += width;
        rect.Width -= width;
    }
}
```

Obtained from [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8a050039-d74a-4ab5-9237-98615e10e303/how-to-paint-a-bold-text-and-normal-text).