# Any way for a combo box with 2 values per line?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview, combobox

I'm looking for an option with which I can use the functionality of a combobox together with a 
listview.

The reason for this is because I have SQL queries which can't have more than 1 output, which I can get in some cases.

E.g. my SQL table looks somewhat like this

`Unique_ID - Name

 123456789 - Simon

 987654321 - Simon`

Basically the same name can be in the database multiple times, each entry with it's own ID.

For the user's sake, I can't have them choose what records to edit based on the ID, instead I have them base the chosen record on the name. When there's more than 1 record resulting from my query though, I get a MySQL exception.

Here's the MySQL query in question:
`"SELECT worldspace from survivor where is_dead = '0' _ and survivor.unique_id = (select unique_id from profile where name = '" & target & "')"`

The output from that query is then used in another `UPDATE` query.

So, is it possible for my combobox to have both the ID & the name as values, with a clear seperation between them so the entire value stays well readable, as it would do in a listview element?

Comment: is this a windows application? winforms? This is really easy to achieve in XAML based technologies, but impossible in winforms. yet another reason why I say winforms is deprecated, and the stackoverflow hackforms zombies come trying to eat my brain

Comment: It's currently in a windows form, yes. If it's so easy to achieve in XAML based apps, how would it be done in a WPF application? It's not a whole lot of change that I'ld need to do to just change this WF to a WPF. PS: Thanks for pointing out the fact I forgot to mention wether it was a winform or WPF.

Comment: Are you wanting to update all records for that name? If so, you could change "survivor.unique_id =" to "survivor.unique_id IN".

Comment: No, just the one which is selected, it's for a MySQL server linked to a game server which houses data like player position, player health, etc. I'm pretty sure if 1 "Simon" wants to be teleported to a location, the other "Simon"'s would kind of get annoyed by the fact they get teleported too :>

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I see you've already gotten the HighCore treatment about how easy everything is in WPF and how much WinForms sucks. But you might be interested to know that you can do this in WinForms, too. You just do it a little bit differently. It should come as no surprise that the standard design idioms differ in WinForms and WPF; that doesn't justify one being "better" than the other, it just means you need to learn how to use the one you're using. (Although, admittedly, some of the fancier stuff is a bit more difficult to achieve using a UI framework that was invented 20 years ago with Windows itself. The power it *does* have is rather remarkable.)

There are two basic ways of formatting the information: everything on a single line (which I believe is what you asked for in the question) or the pieces of information on two lines where each item is basically a two-line unit (which is what HighCore's WPF solution demonstrates).

## Single-Line Format

#### The Simplistic Approach

We'll look at putting everything on a single line first, which really is simple. You don't need columns for separation, you can just use some kind of distinctive separator character when you add the items to the combobox, such as a vertical pipe (`|`) or a dash (`-`) like you used in the question.

This works so well because the `ComboBox.Items.Add` method accepts a parameter of type `Object`, on which it just calls `ToString` to get the value displayed in the control. If you pass it a string, it displays that string.

```
myComboBox.BeginUpdate()
For Each record In myRecordSet
   myComboBox.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} | {1}", record.UniqueID, record.Name))
   ' or even...
   myComboBox.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", record.UniqueID, record.Name))
Next record
myComboBox.EndUpdate()
```

[image]                 OR                [image]

#### An Incremental Improvement Through OOP

You can even pass a custom class to the `Add` method that keeps track of the unique ID and name properties (and anything else you want) and overrides the `ToString` method for display purposes.

```
Public Class Record
    Public Property UniqueID As Long  ' maybe this should be a string too
    Public Property Name As String

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        ' Generate the string that will be displayed in the combobox for this
        ' record, just like we did above when adding it directly to the combobox,
        ' except that in this case, it will be dynamically generated on the fly,
        ' allowing you to also track state information along with each item.
        Return String.Format("{0} | {1}", Me.UniqueID, Me.Name)
    End Function
End Class

' ...

' (somewhere else, when you add the items to the combobox:)
myComboBox.BeginUpdate()
For Each r In myRecordSet
   ' Create a Record object representing this item, and set its properties.
   Dim newRecord As New Record
   newRecord.UniqueID = r.UniqueID
   newRecord.Name     = r.Name
   ' ...etc.

   ' Then, add that object to the combobox.
   myComboBox.Items.Add(newRecord)
Next r
myComboBox.EndUpdate()
```

#### Fixing the Jaggies

Granted, if the first item in each set can be of variable length and you're using a variable-width font (i.e., one that is not monospaced like every UI on the planet does except code editors), the separators won't line up and you won't get two nicely-formatted columns. Instead, it looks all jumbled and ugly.

[image]

It would be nice of the ComboBox control supported tab characters that would handle lining everything up for us automatically, but unfortunately it does not. This is, regrettably, a hard limitation of the underlying Win32 control.

Fixing this ragged-edge problem is possible, but it does get a bit complicated. It requires taking over the drawing of the items in the combobox, referred to as "owner-draw".

To do this, you set its `DrawMode` property to `OwnerDrawFixed` and handle the [`DrawItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.drawitem.aspx) event to manually draw the text. You'll use the [`TextRenderer.DrawText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.drawtext.aspx) method to draw the caption string <sup><sub>(because [that matches what WinForms uses internally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11671909/366904); avoid using `Graphics.DrawString`)</sub></sup>, and [`TextRenderer.MeasureText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.measuretext.aspx) if necessary to get the spacing right. The drawing code can (and should) use all of the default properties provided by the `DrawItemEventArgs` passed as `e`. You don't need `OwnerDrawVariable` mode or to handle the `MeasureItem` event because the width and height of each item cannot vary in this case.

Just to give you an idea, here's a quick-and-dirty implementation that simply divides the drop-down in half vertically:

```
Private Sub myComboBox_DrawItem(sender As Object, e As DrawItemEventArgs) Handles myComboBox.DrawItem
  ' Fill the background.
  e.DrawBackground()

  ' Extract the Record object corresponding to the combobox item to be drawn.
  Dim record As Record = DirectCast(myComboBox.Items(e.Index), Record)
  Dim id As String     = record.UniqueID.ToString()
  Dim name As String   = record.Name

  ' Calculate important positions based on the area of the drop-down box.
  Dim xLeft As Integer   = e.Bounds.Location.X
  Dim xRight As Integer  = xLeft + e.Bounds.Width
  Dim xMid As Integer    = (xRight - xLeft) / 2
  Dim yTop As Integer    = e.Bounds.Location.Y
  Dim yBottom As Integer = yTop + e.Bounds.Height

  ' Draw the first (Unique ID) string in the first half.
  TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, id, e.Font, New Point(xLeft, yTop), e.ForeColor)

  ' Draw the column separator line right down the middle.
  e.Graphics.DrawLine(SystemPens.ButtonFace, xMid, yTop, xMid, yBottom)

  ' Draw the second (Name) string in the second half, adding a bit of padding.
  TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, name, e.Font, New Point(xMid + 5, yTop), e.ForeColor, TextFormatFlags.Left)

  ' Finally, draw the focus rectangle.
  e.DrawFocusRectangle()
End Sub
```

[image]

Now, this is looking pretty good. You can certainly improve on the technique used by the `DrawItem` event handler method, but it works out pretty well as is, so long as the combobox is made the right size for the values it will be displaying.

## Multiple-Line Format

#### Defining a Custom ComboBox Class

The second method, where each item is a two-line group like HighCore's WPF example, is best done by subclassing the built-in ComboBox control and taking complete control its drawing routines. But that's nothing to be afraid of, subclassing a control is a standard WinForms idiom to gain extra control over the UI. (You could, of course, implement all of this by handling events like I did above, but I think subclassing is a much cleaner approach and also promotes reuse if you want to have multiple comboboxes that all behave in a similar fashion.)

Again, you don't need `OwnerDrawVariable` because the height of the items is not going to change. You'll always have two lines, so a fixed height works fine. You just need to make sure that you set the [`ItemHeight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.itemheight.aspx) property to double of its normal value because you're going to have two lines. You could do this the complicated way using `TextRenderer.MeasureText`, or you could do it the easy way by just multiplying the default value by 2. I chose the latter for this demo.

Add this class into your project, and then use the `MultiLineComboBox`control instead of the built-in `System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox`. All of the properties and methods work the same.

```
Public Class MultiLineComboBox : Inherits ComboBox
   Public Sub New()
      ' Call the base class.
      MyBase.New()

      ' Typing a value into this combobox won't make sense, so make it impossible.
      Me.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList

      ' Set the height of each item to be twice its normal value
      ' (because we have two lines instead of one).
      Me.ItemHeight *= 2
   End Sub

   Protected Overrides Sub OnDrawItem(e As DrawItemEventArgs)
      ' Call the base class.
      MyBase.OnDrawItem(e)

      ' Fill the background.
      e.DrawBackground()

      ' Extract the Record object corresponding to the combobox item to be drawn.
      If (e.Index >= 0) Then
         Dim record As Record = DirectCast(Me.Items(e.Index), Record)

         ' Format the item's caption string.
         Dim caption As String = String.Format("ID: {0}{1}Name: {2}", record.UniqueID.ToString(), Environment.NewLine, record.Name)

         ' And then draw that string, left-aligned and vertically centered.
         TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, caption, e.Font, e.Bounds, e.ForeColor, TextFormatFlags.Left Or TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter)
      End If

      ' Finally, draw the focus rectangle.
      e.DrawFocusRectangle()
   End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

#### Adding Fancies and Flourishes

What we've got now isn't bad, but by lavishing a bit more effort on the drawing code in `OnDrawItem`, we can add some extra visual fancies and flourishes.

For example, without the selection rectangle, it would be pretty hard to tell that these are actually two-line units. That's unusual for a combobox control, so for usability reasons your application should go out of its way to make this abundantly clear. One way we might do that is by indenting the second line. You'll recall that I said that the built-in combobox control doesn't support tabs? Well that doesn't apply anymore, since we're doing the drawing ourselves now. We can emulate tabs by adding some extra padding to the beginning of the second line.

If you wanted the labels ("ID:" and "Name:") to be set apart from the actual values, you could do that, too. Perhaps you'd make the labels bold and lighten the text color.

So you see that just by playing with the drawing code, you can create almost any effect you want. We have complete control, and by wrapping it all up in a `MultiLineComboBox` class that can be reused all over the place, the rest of your code doesn't even have to know that anything special is happening. Cool, right?

## Avoiding All the Work

And finally, I would be remiss if I didn't point out that you could skip doing all of this work and [take your pick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899169/multi-column-combobox-controls-for-winforms) of the variety of custom multi-line combobox controls that have already been written.

[This one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3206/Multi-Column-ComboBox) is pretty nifty. It actually just displays a ListView control when you click the drop-down arrow on the combobox. In doing so, you get all of the formatting niceties of the ListView control for free, but it behaves just like a regular ComboBox.

Answer (score 6):

This would be a WPF ComboBox with multiple Lines:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ID, StringFormat='{}ID: {0}'}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, StringFormat='{}Name: {0}'}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Data Item:

```
public class ComboItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Result:

[image]

To all the hackforms zombies: technical superiority speaks by itself.

Comment: Thanks, although I'll use Cody's answer, simply because it saves me the trouble of having to remake all my controls into a WPF app.

I'll definately keep your answer in the back of my head though, in case I need to do another, similar form, then I'll probably use this, easier, method :)

Comment: Can you explain the empty braces in the Text attribute and what they are for?  I'm referring to this bit:  `'{}ID: {0}'}`  What is the purpose of the empty set of braces at the beginning?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway It's a XAML [Escape Sequence for Attribute Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms744986.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is actually way, way easier. Try this:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To dataSet.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1

ComboBox1.Items.Add(dataSet.Tables(0).Rows(i)(0) + " | " + dataSet.Tables(0).Rows(i)(1) 
+ " | " + dataSet.Tables(0).Rows(i)(2))

Next
```

But you have to implement it to your Code and DB