# how to put a newline/tab in a combobox

Tags: c#, .net, csv, combobox

I have a `CSV` file which holds various items. Some of these items I put into a combobox. How can I put a newline and/or tab in the `CSV` file so it will show up as a newline/tab inside the combobox? I have tried `\t` and `\n` but it just shows those in the combobox.

Comment: How are you putting the data into a ComboBox? Is this WinForms or ASP .NET?

Comment: Sadly you can't. Not using the standard html input.

Answer (score 2):

The base `ComboBox` doesn't support special characters like this for its display, they will simply be ignored. If you need this type of functionality you'll need to override the `OnDrawItem` method and draw those items on your own - I do not recommend this. Another option would be to use a more advanced `ComboBox` from a company like Telerik or Infragistics.

Comment: This is mostly right. You probably don't want to override `OnPaint` because you don't want to take *all* of the drawing into your own hands. That would include things like the drop-down arrow that are best left to be painted by the system. Fortunately, the ComboBox control was explicitly designed to support owner-draw, which lets you take *some* but not all of the drawing into your own hands. In this case, you want to override `OnDrawItem`. I wrote up a very detailed answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15516029/366904) in response to a challenge that this could not be done in WinForms.

Comment: @CodyGray, fantastic correction! Thank you very much. I'll edit the answer. Oh, and it can be done, I've done it as well. I'm going to jump over and have a look at your answer!