# How to remove vertical divider in combobox

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, combobox

I have a combo box drop down with a vertical separator.(Please refer imgae 4 in the below link [Any way for a combo box with 2 values per line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514698/any-way-for-a-combo-box-with-2-values-per-line)) In that image towards right of the vertical separator there are names, but in my drop down its blank. I don't want that vertical line. I've reffered and tried all help online, nothing works. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming that image 4 is this one?

[image]

If so, removing the vertical line is *really* easy to do. All you have to do is remove the code that draws it:

```
' Draw the column separator line right down the middle.
e.Graphics.DrawLine(SystemPens.ButtonFace, xMid, yTop, xMid, yBottom)
```

Honestly, you should have been able to figure out how to do this for yourself. The complete code is shown right above the image, and it is pretty well-commented. But perhaps I'm biased…