# Type "Record" is not defined in custom class vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, combobox, visual-studio-2019, .net-4.7.2

I'm following the thread below to create the multi-line combobox. I'm currently using Visual Studio 2019, and that thread is from 2013.

[Any way for a combo box with 2 values per line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514698/any-way-for-a-combo-box-with-2-values-per-line/15516029)

Code that I copied:

```
    Public Class MultiLineComboBox : Inherits ComboBox
   Public Sub New()
      ' Call the base class.
      MyBase.New()

      ' Typing a value into this combobox won't make sense, so make it impossible.
      Me.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList

      ' Set the height of each item to be twice its normal value
      ' (because we have two lines instead of one).
      Me.ItemHeight *= 2
   End Sub

   Protected Overrides Sub OnDrawItem(e As DrawItemEventArgs)
      ' Call the base class.
      MyBase.OnDrawItem(e)

      ' Fill the background.
      e.DrawBackground()

      ' Extract the Record object corresponding to the combobox item to be drawn.
      If (e.Index >= 0) Then
         Dim record As Record = DirectCast(Me.Items(e.Index), Record)

         ' Format the item's caption string.
         Dim caption As String = String.Format("ID: {0}{1}Name: {2}", record.UniqueID.ToString(), Environment.NewLine, record.Name)

         ' And then draw that string, left-aligned and vertically centered.
         TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, caption, e.Font, e.Bounds, e.ForeColor, TextFormatFlags.Left Or TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter)
      End If

      ' Finally, draw the focus rectangle.
      e.DrawFocusRectangle()
   End Sub
End Class
```

I created a class named MultiLineComboBox, followed the instruction exactly, and it says "Type 'Record' is not defined." I have been searching for answers on the type "record" or DirectCast (e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/directcast-operator), but none of them has helped me so far.

My reputation is currently <50 so I cannot leave a comment on the answer of that thread either. Could you all please help me with this?

(added tag visual-studio-2019 and .net-4.7.2 in case VS or .NET version is the issue)

Comment: There are loads of links in the answer to that question and you haven't told us which one you're using. It seems likely that you are supposed to have created that `Record` class yourself. It's obviously not a standard .NET type so where do you think it's supposed to be coming from?

Comment: @jmcilhinney I am so sorry I pasted the wrong link. Here's the correct one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15514698/any-way-for-a-combo-box-with-2-values-per-line/15516029

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the whole answer. The `Record` class is declared there; you need it, too, and you want to change the code to match the fields for your combobox.

Comment: Got it. I did not read through the OOP section that the answer mentioned