# How to draw text on TabControl's tab exactly the same way TabControl does?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I am trying to set *DrawMode* to *OwnerDrawFixeddraw* and then draw tab title the same way *TabControl* does with *Normal* *DrawMode*, but *DrawString* method with default parameters gives different results.

In the example below if text is set to *Lorem ipsum* it works, but if it's set to digits - it draws outside of tab area. Yet *TabControl* with Normal *DrawMode* draws everything correctly, how to do the same manually?

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TabWidthIssue
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."; // Works fine!
            var text = "1234567890-1234567890-1234567890-1234567890-1234567890-123456789X"; // Does not fit!

            // TabControl with OwnerDrawFixed
            var ownerDrawFixedTabControl = new TabControl()
            {
                DrawMode = TabDrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed,
                Parent = this,
                Dock = DockStyle.Top,
            };

            ownerDrawFixedTabControl.DrawItem += new DrawItemEventHandler(ownerDrawFixedTabControl_DrawItem);

            ownerDrawFixedTabControl.TabPages.Add(new TabPage(text));

            // TabControl with Normal
            var normalTabControl = new TabControl()
            {
                DrawMode = TabDrawMode.Normal,
                Parent = this,
                Dock = DockStyle.Top,
            };

            normalTabControl.TabPages.Add(new TabPage(text));
        }

        void ownerDrawFixedTabControl_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
        {
            var tabControl = sender as TabControl;
            var tabPage = tabControl.TabPages[e.Index];

            var format = new StringFormat
            {
                FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.NoWrap,
                Trimming = StringTrimming.None
            };

            using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Color.Black))
                e.Graphics.DrawString(tabPage.Text, e.Font, brush, tabControl.GetTabRect(e.Index), format);
        }
    }
}
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGBN7.png)

**Update 1** The task of "drawing text" the same way may be replaced by "measuring the text the same way". I know the size of the text I am going to draw (with either `DrawString` or `DrawText`) but I need to ensure the tab is wide enough. The width from `TextRenderer.MeasureText` do no match the actual width of tab created.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7268238/1997232).

Comment: All the native controls use TextRenderer.DrawText() to render text.  It is subtly different from DrawString().  It is otherwise up to you to ensure the tab is wide enough to fit the text, do avoid something as drastically impractical as that string.

Comment: @HansPassant The width of the tab is calculated automatically based on the text, is there any alternative way to explicitly specify tab width (except for 'ItemSize' property for I need tabs to be of different widths).

Answer (score 1):

framework uses this

```
TextRenderer.DrawText(g, tabItemText, font, contentBounds, textColor, flags);
```

Comment: A little information on the exact `flags` provided to the call might be useful, otherwise +1.

Comment: Yes, we can see that in the docs, but you say that the framework uses the call, so it would be important to know the exact combination of values to achieve the same result that the original implementation renders.

Comment: Thanks @Tom! But as @ThorstenDittmar mentioned, the exact match is still not achieved, I tried flags `TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter | TextFormatFlags.SingleLine` from [TabRenderer.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/TabRenderer.cs) but the results are still different. I shall update my post.

Comment: @Eugene years later... While I'm still trying to figure out why my `TabControl` is drawing tab text even with `OwnerDrawFixed` (after `DrawItem` is called), I can tell you if you adjust `contentBounds` to be `e.Bounds.Offset(1, 1)` it will draw correctly.