# How to estimate the length of a to-be-printed string?

Tags: c#, winforms, measurestring

I am trying to estimate the length of a printed string.

```
Font newFont = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Point);
label1.Font = newFont;
labe1.Text = "300028";
Graphics g = Graphics.FromHwnd(label1.Handle);
SizeF txtSize = g.MeasureString(label1.Text, label1.Font);
```

txtSize is {Width=60.3177, Height=19.875} points.

> The actual width should be 60.3177 * 0.353 = 21.29 mm
>
> where  (1 point = 1/72 inch = 0.353 mm)

On paper (printed with Word) the width is about 13.5 mm

Why do we get such a big difference between the value computed with MeasureString (21.29 mm) and the real one (13.5 mm)?

I am aware of the [limitations of the MeasureString method](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2118/Bypass-Graphics-MeasureString-limitations) but I do not think this cannot justify such a big difference.

What I am missing?

Answer (score 4):

Because you initialize your `Graphics` object wrong. You are using a *display* handle, not a *print* handle.

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7055237/993547) your `Graphics` object should be obtained using the [`PrinterSettings.CreateMeasurementGraphics`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6xfh9y29(v=vs.110).aspx) method on a [`PrintDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Graphics g = pd.PrinterSettings.CreateMeasurementGraphics();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Using the print handle I get Width=62,83094 (I would expect something like 38)

Comment: Did you set the font size to millimeters? `new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Millimeter);`

Comment: I use GraphicsUnit.Point where 1 point = 1/72 inch = 0.353 mm to my understanding

Comment: But we are talking print, then use print measurements. (You may be running into other DPI settings?)

Answer (score 0):

Printing units are by default in hundredths of an inch, not 72ths of an inch.

As the other answer mentions, you need to use `PrinterSettings.CreateMeasurementGraphics` to get a graphics object that will be configured the right way to measure text for printing.